# How to specify max number of rows to be written in one csv file in oracle?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g

I am using the procedure below as mentioned in [this](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::NO::P11_QUESTION_ID:88212348059) to dump data into csv.
This writes data into a single csv file test.csv. In case table is very big, I don't want to write into one csv file. I want to specify a threshold of 10k into it with a file name as

> test_sequenceNumber _timeOfOpeningInYYYYMMDDHHMMSSsss.csv

so for example if row count of a table is 15k then I should have 2 files:

```
test_1_20181112012830000.csv 
test_2_20181112012835005.csv
```

How can we I achieve this by modifying the below SP?

```
create or replace procedure dump_table_to_csv
    ( p_tname in varchar2
    , p_dir in varchar2
    )
as
    l_output utl_file.file_type;
    l_theCursor integer default dbms_sql.open_cursor;
    l_columnValue varchar2(4000);
    l_status integer;
    l_query varchar2(1000)
        default 'select * from ' || p_tname;
    l_colCnt number := 0;
    l_separator varchar2(1);
    l_descTbl dbms_sql.desc_tab;
    p_filename varchar2(100) := 'test.csv' ;
begin
    l_output := utl_file.fopen( p_dir, p_filename, 'w' , 32760); 
    execute immediate 'alter session set nls_date_format=''dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'' ';

    dbms_sql.parse( l_theCursor, l_query, dbms_sql.native );
    dbms_sql.describe_columns( l_theCursor, l_colCnt, l_descTbl );

    for i in 1 .. l_colCnt loop
        utl_file.put( l_output, l_separator || '"' || l_descTbl(i).col_name || '"' );
        dbms_sql.define_column( l_theCursor, i, l_columnValue, 4000 );
        l_separator := ',';
    end loop;

    utl_file.new_line( l_output );

    l_status := dbms_sql.execute(l_theCursor);

    while (dbms_sql.fetch_rows(l_theCursor) > 0 ) loop
        l_separator := '';

        for i in 1 .. l_colCnt loop
            dbms_sql.column_value( l_theCursor, i, l_columnValue );
            utl_file.put( l_output, l_separator || l_columnValue );
            l_separator := ',';
        end loop;

        utl_file.new_line(l_output );
    end loop;

    dbms_sql.close_cursor(l_theCursor);
    utl_file.fclose(l_output );

    execute immediate 'alter session set nls_date_format=''dd-MON-yy'' ';
exception
    when others then
        utl_file.fclose( l_output );
        execute immediate 'alter session set nls_date_format=''dd-MON-yy'' ';
        raise;
end;
```

**EDIT1:**
I was trying of applying a logic of `mod(num_rows_written,10000) == 0` it's time to close old file and start a new one but just stuck at a point that, what should be top most loop to continue the same operation on new file ?

Comment: Any reason for down-voting ? The solution of this problem must be useful for many.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's a fairly straightforward task. All you need to do is close the old file and open a new one. There's no need for outer loop, all you need is to put a condition and retrace the steps for preparing the csv.

```
create or replace procedure dump_table_to_csv
    ( p_tname in varchar2
    , p_dir in varchar2
    )
as
    l_output utl_file.file_type;
    l_theCursor integer default dbms_sql.open_cursor;
    l_columnValue varchar2(4000);
    l_status integer;
    l_query varchar2(1000)
        default 'select * from ' || p_tname;
    l_colCnt number := 0;
    l_separator varchar2(1);
    l_descTbl dbms_sql.desc_tab;
    l_file_seq number := 1;
    l_rows_written number := 0;
    l_nls_format varchar2(200);
begin
    l_output := utl_file.fopen( p_dir, 'test_'||l_file_seq||'_'||to_char(systimestamp, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISSFF3'), 'w' , 32760); 
    l_file_seq := l_file_seq + 1;
    SELECT value into l_nls_format
      FROM   nls_session_parameters
     WHERE  parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT';
    execute immediate 'alter session set nls_date_format=''dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'' ';

    dbms_sql.parse( l_theCursor, l_query, dbms_sql.native );
    dbms_sql.describe_columns( l_theCursor, l_colCnt, l_descTbl );

    for i in 1 .. l_colCnt loop
        utl_file.put( l_output, l_separator || '"' || l_descTbl(i).col_name || '"' );
        dbms_sql.define_column( l_theCursor, i, l_columnValue, 4000 );
        l_separator := ',';
    end loop;

    utl_file.new_line( l_output );

    l_status := dbms_sql.execute(l_theCursor);

    while (dbms_sql.fetch_rows(l_theCursor) > 0 ) loop

        if l_rows_written >= 10000 then
          utl_file.fclose( l_output );
          l_output := utl_file.fopen( p_dir, 'test_'||l_file_seq||'_'||to_char(systimestamp, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISSFF3'), 'w' , 32760);
          for i in 1 .. l_colCnt loop
              utl_file.put( l_output, l_separator || '"' || l_descTbl(i).col_name || '"' );
              l_separator := ',';
          end loop;
          utl_file.new_line( l_output );

          l_file_seq := l_file_seq + 1;
          l_rows_written := 0;
        end if;

        l_separator := '';

        for i in 1 .. l_colCnt loop
            dbms_sql.column_value( l_theCursor, i, l_columnValue );
            utl_file.put( l_output, l_separator || l_columnValue );
            l_separator := ',';
        end loop;

        utl_file.new_line(l_output );
        l_rows_written := l_rows_written + 1;
    end loop;

    dbms_sql.close_cursor(l_theCursor);
    utl_file.fclose(l_output );

    execute immediate 'alter session set nls_date_format='''||l_nls_format||''' ';
exception
    when others then
        utl_file.fclose( l_output );
        execute immediate 'alter session set nls_date_format='''||l_nls_format||''' ';
        raise;
end;
```

It might be a good idea to offload the code for preparing CSV to a separate (sub)procedure to avoid code duplication. Also beware that original procedure has a nasty side effect of overriding your `nls_date_format` to `dd-MON-yy` without any regards to how it was set before execution; I fixed that.

Comment: thanks for the answer. The logic i applied is in below answer.